# Data from previous inputs persist when using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to allow a user to switch back and forth between 2 different sets of inputs. To do this, I am using a ternary operator to render a different set of inputs based on the state.

My problem with my current code is that if I type a value in, then switch to the other form, the value from the previous form persists. I am confused why this is happening.

Testable address: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-sea-towhpr?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("a");

  const handleModeChange = (e) => {
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    setMode(checked ? "b" : "a");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleModeChange} />
        {mode === "a" ? (
          <div>
            <label>Item A:</label>
            <input />
            <br />
            <label>Item B:</label>
            <input />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <label>Item Z:</label>
            <input />
            <br />
            <label>Item X:</label>
            <input />
            <br />
            <label>Item Y:</label>
            <input />
            <br />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React tries to update DOM nodes (`div`, `label` and `input` in this case) instead of destroying them and creating new nodes. This means that if the tree your component returns matches, the inputs will keep their values.

Specifically, in mode A you have:

```
<div>
    <label>Item A:</label>
    <input />
    <br />
    <label>Item B:</label>
    <input />
</div>
```

and in mode B you have:

```
<div>
    <label>Item Z:</label>
    <input />
    <br />
    <label>Item X:</label>
    <input />
    <br />
    <label>Item Y:</label>
    <input />
    <br />
</div>
```

When changing from A to B, React makes following changes:

- change label `textContent` from `Item A:` to `Item Z:`
- change label `textContent` from `Item B:` to `Item X:`
- add new `br`, `label`, `input` and `br`

When chaning back to A, React make following changes:

- change label `textContent` from `Item Z:` back to `Item A:`
- change label `textContent` from `Item X:` back to `Item B:`
- delete extra `br`, `label`, `input` and `br`

As you can see, nowhere does it make a change for inputs.

You can overcome this issue by giving React a hint that you do not want this optimization and would prefer to destroy and create it again by using `key` property:

```
{mode === "a" ? (
  <div key="a">
    <label>Item A:</label>
    <input />
    <br />
    <label>Item B:</label>
    <input />
  </div>
) : (
  <div key="b">
    <label>Item Z:</label>
    <input />
    <br />
    <label>Item X:</label>
    <input />
    <br />
    <label>Item Y:</label>
    <input />
    <br />
  </div>
)}
```

When you provide a `key` like this, React will understand the two `div`s are different and it will stop trying to make minimum amount of changes.

You may have heard about `key` for rendering arrays, that's just a special case of this behaviour.

Comment: Great answer. Also, be aware that the entered values won't be maintained *at all* now, because React will completely remount these, wiping out the entered texts. To preserve these values across renders will require making them "controlled" components – saving the values to state, instead of letting the browser do that for them: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable

Comment: Good addition. Also, if you use state to handle the values, you don't need the `key`s anymore because using `value={something}` on all of the inputs will solve the issue in another way.